# Why is it converting 0112 into 74?

Tags: java

When i assign 0112 into 'int' and simply print value of int, its print 74 value of int.
Why it is print value 74 of 0112 ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0112;
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

Output :-

```
74
```

Please any one can suggests me.

Comment: 0112 is intepreted as [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) value so in decimal it is 74.

Comment: the first chapters of the Java Language Specification are kind of important. E.g. [3.10.1. Integer Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)

Comment: @michalk Thanks for reply, So why it is takes as a octal if append 0.

Comment: Check the link which Carlos posted.